# How to find rectangle intersection in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, gis, computational-geometry

Having list of rectangles parallel to axis in form `(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)`:

```
rectangles = [
    Rectangle(90,40,110,70),
    Rectangle(10,40,40,70),
    Rectangle(75,60,95,80),
    Rectangle(30,20,60,50),
    Rectangle(100,20,130,50),
    Rectangle(70,10,85,40)
]
```

I need to get list of groups of rectangles, where each rectangle intersects with at least one other:

```
[
    (Rectangle(10,40,40,70), Rectangle(30,20,60,50)), 
    (Rectangle(70,10,85,40)), 
    (Rectangle(75,60,95,80), Rectangle(90,40,110,70), Rectangle(100,20,130,50))
]
```

The algorithm can't be naive, it needs to be fast.

What I tried:

1. Find python interval tree implementation - I couldn't find anything good...
2. I tried this repo: https://github.com/booo/rectangleintersection/blob/master/rectangleIntersection.py, it works with the example above but fails with real world data.
3. I read through [scikit image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html) and [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) documentation but didn't find algorithms for rectangle intersection.

Comment: what are the four values in each rectangle? definitely not a point in a 2D plane.

Comment: @PhamTrung: minx, miny, max, maxy

Comment: So these rectangles are parallel with Ox and Oy axis?

Comment: @richsilv - 1. Each rectangle intersects with at least one other.
2. By fast I mean faster than O^2 as I can do it comparing each rectangle with another. In ideal case it should have O complexity as good as in theory.

Comment: "Rectangle" that you use is not standard python.   where do you import it from?  Guess you are using matplotlib, but that has different parameters for defining Rectangles?

Comment: @Joop - that doesn't really matter, if you show me working solution using rectangles from matplotlib I will be happy as well.

Comment: This problem is a classic and should be solved in O(nlogn), you want to have a full implementation?

Comment: Now I'm tempted to write this.

Comment: @PhamTrung - problem is classic, yes. But is there any 'classic' implementation - I mean well known, robust python library that would solve it?

Comment: So you should state that in the question, just about to give you some explanations :)

Comment: @PhamTrung - yes, I don't need explanations, I need to solve real life problem - I have an image with lots of small regions detected by scikit image. I need to merge them in larger regions.

Comment: What about sorting the list of rectangles by minx? Then you could compare each rectangle R with only the ones whose minx'es lie within (minx, miny) of R. Still O^2, but better than brute-force.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intersecting rectangles can be viewed as connected nodes in a graph, and sets of "transitively" intersecting rectangles as [Connected Components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29). To find out which rectangles intersect, we first do a [Plane Sweep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm). To make this reasonably fast we need an [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). [Banyan](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Banyan) provides one:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain
from banyan import SortedDict, OverlappingIntervalsUpdator

def closed_regions(rects):

    # Sweep Line Algorithm to set up adjacency sets:
    neighbors = defaultdict(set)
    status = SortedDict(updator=OverlappingIntervalsUpdator)
    events = sorted(chain.from_iterable(
            ((r.left, False, r), (r.right, True, r)) for r in set(rects)))
    for _, is_right, rect in events:
        for interval in status.overlap(rect.vertical):
            neighbors[rect].update(status[interval])
        if is_right:
            status.get(rect.vertical, set()).discard(rect)
        else:
            status.setdefault(rect.vertical, set()).add(rect)

    # Connected Components Algorithm for graphs:
    seen = set()
    def component(node, neighbors=neighbors, seen=seen, see=seen.add):
        todo = set([node])
        next_todo = todo.pop
        while todo:
            node = next_todo()
            see(node)
            todo |= neighbors[node] - seen
            yield node
    for node in neighbors:
        if node not in seen:
            yield component(node)
```

`rect.vertical` BTW is the tuple `(rect.top, rect.bottom)`.

Time complexity is `O(n log n + k)`, where `n` is the number of rectangles and `k` the number of actual intersections. So it's pretty close to optimal.

edit: Because there was some confusion, I need to add that the rectangles are expected to have `left <= right` and `top <= bottom`. IOW, the origin of the coordinate system they are in is in the upper left corner, not in the lower left corner as is usual in geometry.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely give it a try!

Comment: Regarding your link: `horizontal` should be `(self.left, self.right)`. But the main problem is that my code assumes a computer graphics coordinate system where the origin is in the upper left corner, not the lower left corner like in mathematical geometry. So the parameter list of `Rectanle.__init__()` should be `self, left, top, right, bottom`, with `left <= right` and `top <= bottom`. I tested it like so and it seems to work.

Comment: Also, `closed_regions()` returns an iterator of iterators, so you should `print(list(region))`.

Comment: BTW, you could also change the definition of `vertical` to `(self.bottom, self.top)`. Then you could keep the origin of the coordinate system in the lower left corner.

Comment: Like this https://gist.github.com/mnowotka/8729240? It's still return nothing. Can you publish your gist so I can see it?

Comment: No, I meant *either* you change `__init__()` *or* you change `vertical`. Look [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8733039) and [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8733048). I just saw that the `__repr__()`of the first link is not correct. `self.top` and `self.bottom` should be swapped.

Comment: Works like a charm, great piece of code, extremely helpful, thank you very much!